# Can the host object events be received in the Javascript side?

Tags: javascript, com, atl, webview2

I created a Com object using ATL C++

```
interface IHostObjectSample2 : IDispatch
{
    [propget, id(2), helpstring("Property.")] HRESULT Property([out, retval] BSTR* stringResult);
    [propput, id(2), helpstring("Property.")] HRESULT Property([in] BSTR stringValue);
};

dispinterface _IHostObjectSample2Events
{
    methods:
        [id(1), helpstring("message")] void Event();
};

coclass HostObjectSample2
{
    [default] interface IHostObjectSample2;
    [default, source] dispinterface _IHostObjectSample2Events;
};
```

I added the Com object to script using AddHostObjectToScript
`m_Webview->AddHostObjectToScript(L"sample", &remoteObjectAsVariant));`

I can call methods/functions from the Script side

I want to fire the event `_IHostObjectSample2Events::Event` in c++ side and received it in the Javascript side

something like  `window.chrome.webview.hostObjects.sample.addEventListener("Event", () => { do something });`

Comment: This is not documented, and I doubt it wouldn't be if it was implemented because it's a quite complex mechanic (IConnectionPoint, requires COM message pump, etc.). Only Microsoft can answer that (I see have posted the question here https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/677)

Comment: It did not work with IE scripting, I don't anticipate connection points will be implemented with webview2 either.

Comment: You can simply call: `WebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync(String)` from C++ and call a normal javascript `function`.

Comment: @RomanR. It's working with IE, Example here

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35532/C-COM-Object-for-Use-In-JavaScript-HTML-Including

like this :
<script for="myComComponent" event="MyFirstEvent(args)" language="javascript">
function myComComponent::MyFirstEvent(args) {
}

Comment: I stand corrected then. IE11 however also supported a different method of supplying a callback interface from C++ end. I think this is what is working here with WebView2. Not sure if the aged mechanism of connection poins is intended to be supported.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately events aren't currently directly supported with WebView2's AddHostObjectToScript. You can file this as a feature request in the [WebView2Feedback project](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues).